# Readonly field is not rendered correctly

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

In the `SubscriptionPlan` class below `MonthlyCost` is rendered as NaN or 0.  See the first two lines of html below.

I don't know if this is a react problem or Typescript or ??.

class

```
export default class SubscriptionPlan {
    public Cost: number = 0;                           
    public BillingPeriods: number = 2;                 
    public get MonthlyCost(): number { return (this.Cost / 12) * this.BillingPeriods }
};
```

variable set in react:

```
const [selectedPlan, setSelectedPlan] = useState(appState.SubscriptionPlan); // not null
```

html (jsx)

```
<span>{selectedPlan === null ? 0 : selectedPlan.MonthlyCost}</span> //  renders NaN
<span>{selectedPlan?.MonthlyCost ?? 0}</span> // renders 0

<span >{12 / (selectedPlan?.BillingPeriods ?? 2)} Months</span> // renders correctly
<span >{selectedPlan?.Cost ?? 0}</span> // renders correctly
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "clientapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.56",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "msal": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "4.1.0-dev.20201015", // also tried 4.1.0-beta
    "use-async-effect": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "compile-styles": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 ./src/App.scss ./src/App.css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problems.  But in your tsconfig make sure that you are targeting at least es5 or else you will have problems using `get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried you problem as:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class SubscriptionPlan {
  public Cost: number = 60;
  public BillingPeriods: number = 2;
  public get MonthlyCost(): number {
    return (this.Cost / 12) * this.BillingPeriods;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [selectedPlan, setSelectedPlan] = useState(new SubscriptionPlan());
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>{selectedPlan === null ? 0 : selectedPlan.MonthlyCost}</span>
      <br/>
      <span>{selectedPlan?.MonthlyCost ?? 0}</span>
      <br/>
      <span>{12 / (selectedPlan?.BillingPeriods ?? 2)} Months</span>
      <br/>
      <span>{selectedPlan?.Cost ?? 0}</span>
    </div>
  );
```

and got the below output:

```
10
10
6 Months
60
```

That seems correctly working. The only problem I may see is you might not using ES5 or higher which is required for "Accessors".

> Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and
> higher.ts(1056)

Hope this may help...